# Postgres isn't accepting TCP/IP on port 5432

Tags: postgresql, docker

I've got this docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./services/users
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
    expose:
      - 5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_ENV=production
      - APP_SETTINGS=project.config.ProductionConfig
      - DATABASE_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_prod
      - DATABASE_URL_DEPTS=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/depts_prod
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/users_test
      - DATABASE_TEST_URL_DEPTS=postgres://postgres:postgres@users-db:5432/depts_test
    depends_on:
      - users-db

  users-db:
    build:
      context: ./services/users/project/db
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    expose:
      - 5432
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres

  nginx:
    build:
      context: ./services/nginx
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-prod
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 80:80
    depends_on:
      - users
```

from Postgres I'm getting error saying:

```
(psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: Connection refused
    Is the server running on host "users-db" (172.19.0.2) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

The port 5432 is defined as to be exposed so why it isn't accepting connections ? When in development I'm using '5436:5432' on Postgres and '5000:5001' on the Flask app and it works just fine.

Dockerfile for the Flask app:

```
FROM python:3.6.9-slim

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y netcat && \
    apt-get clean

RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./entrypoint.sh /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/src/app/entrypoint.sh

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["/usr/src/app/entrypoint-prod.sh"]
```

Dockerfile for the Postgres:

```
FROM postgres:11.2-alpine

ADD users/create.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

entrypoint:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo 'Waiting for postgres ...'

while ! nc -z users-db 5432; do
  sleep 0.1
done

echo 'PostgreSQL started'

gunicorn -b 0.0.0.0:5000 manage:app
```

Comment: Without knowing if the container is on the same server and how docker ends up flowing into postgres, I might suggest reviewing the pg_hba.conf file to confirm postgres will allow connections from the docker source.

Comment: What's your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD` in your `Dockerfile`?  Seems like Postgres isn't running perhaps because one of those is either missing or improperly formed

Comment: Are you suggesting `bash`ing into Postgres container and look for the file ? The container will give me its database shell interface only and the container where Flask app lives won't contain the file as it is a separate container altogether.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that you need to `bash` into the Postgres container, but that something's either not running or listening.  Typically, I use `ports` instead of `expose` in `docker-compose.yml`.  Also, you may need to add `depends_on: users-db` in your `users` section (instead of using `nc -z users-db` in the entrypoint).